# Display image command line in Windows 10 using IrfanView

Tags: windows, image, unix, display, irfanview

I'm using windows 10, connected to a server using bash. This server runs unix and it have eog and gwenview to display images. I can't use this programs in windows, so I was looking for one that does the same in windows. I tried IrfanView but I don't know how to use it, I don't get the commands. Like in Unix was something like: `eog xxxxx.png` and then the image was displayed. How can I do that in windows?
Thank you so much!!!

EDIT: In Unix server I get this error when trying to display:

```
display-im6.q16: unable to open X server `' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/432.
```

I want to display the image from the unix server but I'm running it in a Windows 10 computer.

Comment: Please add more details how you connect to the server. Using SSH maybe?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your requirements in the following way: You want to display an image file that is stored on the UNIX server on your local Windows system.

Please clarify in the question what connection you use to access the UNIX server.

You have several options:

- Transfer the image file to your Windows system and display it with an image viewer program running on Windows. If you use an SSH connection you might use a program like **WinSCP**. This is probably the easier solution.
- If your connection allows to tunnel data you can use it to show the output of an image viewer program running on the UNIX system in one of several ways

  - Run an X server on your Windows system and use X forwarding to tunnel the X connection to the Windows system.
  - Run an X server with a virtual display (e.g. `Xvnc`) on the UNIX server use a corresponding viewer on your Windows system.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the answer. I'm using ssh, so maybe the first one is the best one? How can I use it?

Comment: @Georgia Please add the information about using SSH to your question as I already wrote in a comment and the answer. Your question "How can I use it?" is not at all clear. My answer is: 1. Install it. 2. Run it. You should be more specific about what you are having problems with.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't log in but now works perfect! thank you so so much:) last question, is it possible to display the images without downlading them in my windows computer? Just displaying them in WinSCP

Comment: Please check the documentation/help of WinSCP. Maybe you can double click the image file on the remote system, but technically it must be transferred to the local computer, so this may hide this fact by silently transferring the file to a temporary directory.